# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'batch'

Tags: python, django, django-models

**MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

# Create your models here.
class studentDetails(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    roll_no = models.BigIntegerField()
    b1='2013'
    b2='2014'
    b3='2015'
    b4='2016'
    batch_CHOICES = (
        (b1, '2013'),
        (b2, '2014'),
        (b3, '2015'),
        (b4, '2016'),
    )
    batch = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=batch_CHOICES, default=b1)
    br=''
    cse= 'cse'
    ece= 'ece'
    mae= 'mae'
    branch_CHOICES = (
        (br, 'branch'),
        (cse, 'CSE'),
        (ece, 'ECE'),
        (mae, 'MAE'),
    )
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=branch_CHOICES,default=br)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 100, null= True)
    contact = models.BigIntegerField()
    address = models.TextField(max_length = 300)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Every time I run `python manage.py migrate` command it shows me this error.

```
(portal) C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\GBPEC_PORTAL>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, student
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying student.0002_auto_20160820_1313...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 356, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 202, in handle
    targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 97, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 132, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 237, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 204, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 495, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\schema.py", line 117, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 577, in _alter_field
    old_default = self.effective_default(old_field)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 221, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 755, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 747, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1832, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'batch'

(portal) C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\GBPEC-PORTAL\portal\GBPEC_PORTAL>
```

**0002_auto_20160820_1313.py**
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    # Generated by Django 1.10 on 2016-08-20 07:43
    from **future** import unicode_literals

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('student', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='studentdetails',
            name='batch',
            field=models.IntegerField(choices=[('batch', 'batch'), (2013, '2013'), (2014, '2014'), (2015, '2015'), (2016, '2016')], default='batch'),
        ),
    ]
```

Even though batch is not even an integer, it is giving the same error. 
I also tried removing this field but it is not working at all.
I don't know why it is giving me this error.
Help me guys to fix this error.

Comment: Can you post the `student.0002_auto_20160820_1313` migration file?

Comment: 0002_auto_20160820_1313.py

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.10 on 2016-08-20 07:43
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('student', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='studentdetails',
            name='batch',
            field=models.IntegerField(choices=[('batch', 'batch'), (2013, '2013'), (2014, '2014'), (2015, '2015'), (2016, '2016')], default='batch'),
        ),
    ]`

Comment: Delete this and subsequent migration files for the student model, run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `migrate` again.

Comment: `django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration student.0003_auto_20160820_1313 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('student', '0002_auto_20160820_1313')`

Comment: now it is giving me this error on command `python manage,py makemigrations`

Comment: Delete the subsequent migration files for as well.

Comment: This was just the case of previously having a different field and therefore botching the migrations. Voting to close as not reproduceable since all details are not present in the question.